# Excel formula to get the count of certain value based on odd/even line

Tags: excel

I have this data in Excel.

```
    A               B           C
--------------------------------------
Line Number      Value #1    Value #2  
1                21          35
2                21          27
3                21          18
4                10          47
5                50          5
6                37          68
7                10          21
8                75          21
```

I tried to calculate the total "21" based on odd line number. In this situation, the answer should be 3. However, neither" IF(MOD(A1:A8,2)=1,COUNTIF(B1:C8,21)) " nor " {IF(MOD(A1:A8,2)=1,COUNTIF(B1:C8,21))} "worked and Google didn't yield anything helpful. Could anyone help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for odd lines:

=SUM(COUNTIF(A:B,21)-SUMPRODUCT((A:B=21)*(MOD(ROW(A:B),2)=0)))

there may be a better way of writing this formula.

---

Use this to count even lines:
=SUMPRODUCT((A:B=21)*(MOD(ROW(A:B),2)=0))